# re.search Multiple lines Python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

re.search with \s or '\n' is not finding the multiline i'm trying to search for.

Portion of Source:

```
Date/Time:
2013-08-27 17:05:36 

----- BEGIN SEARCH -----

GENERAL DATA:
NAME:   AB12
SECTOR: 
999,999
CONTROLLED BY:  Player
ALLIANCE:   Aliance
ONLINE: 1 seconds ago
SIZE:   Large
HOMEWORLD:  NO
APPROVAL RATING:    100%
PRODUCTION RATE:    100%

RESOURCE DATA:
POWER:  0 / 0
BUILDINGS:  0 / 20
ORE:    80,000 / 80,000
CRYSTAL:    80,000 / 80,000
POPULATION: 40,000 / 40,000

BUILDING DATA:
N/A

UNIT DATA:
WYVERN(S):  100

----- END SEARCH -----
```

Looking at it in Notepad++ I see "BUILDING DATA:(LF)"

Full Code

```
lines = open('scan.txt','r').readlines()
for a in lines:
    if re.search(r"\A\d", a):
        digits = a
        if re.search(r"2013", digits):
            date.append(digits[:19])
            count +=1
        elif re.search(r",", digits):
            clean = digits.rstrip()
            sector = clean.split(',')
            x.append(sector[0])
            y.append(sector[1])
    elif re.search(r"CONTROLLED BY:", a):
        player.append(a[15:].rstrip())
    elif re.search(r"ALLIANCE:", a):
        alliance.append(a[10:].rstrip())
    elif re.search(r"SIZE:", a):
        size.append(a[6:].rstrip())
    elif re.findall('BUILDING DATA:\sN/A', a, re.M):
        def_grid = ''
        print "Didn't find it"
        defense.append(def_grid)
        defense_count +=1
    elif re.search(r"DEFENSE GRID", a):
        def_grid = a[16:].rstrip()
        print "defense found"
        defense_count +=1
```

But I am not having anything returned.

I need to put an empty spacer in when "DEFENSE GRID" doesn't exist after "BUILDING DATA:"

I know i'm missing something and I've tried reading up on re.search but i'm not able to find any thorough examples that explain how the multiline works.

Comment: A [sscce](http://sscce.org/) would be nice. Its hard to figure out what exactly the problem is..

Comment: I think you forgot to 'import re' and this example does not work out of the box. date is not defined...

Answer (score 14):

```
re.findall("BUILDING DATA:\nN/A",a,re.MULTILINE)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do just what you did, but using `re.findall` instead of `re.search`:

```
re.findall('BUILDING DATA:\nN/A', a, re.M)
#['BUILDING DATA:\nN/A']
```

---

EDIT:

The problem is that you are currently reading line-by-line. In order to detect a pattern that belongs to two or more lines, you have to consider the string as a whole, maybe doing:

```
s = ''.join(lines)
```

which is ok if `lines` is not so big, and then use `s` to perform your multi-line searches...

Comment: I added more of what I was working on. The re.findall didn't seem to help.

Comment: lol, I thought it was just going to be a simple syntax error on my part... Decided to add the rest to explain how i'm trying to use it...

Comment: @Xariec I've added an explanation that seems to be the root cause of your problem...

Comment: I wonder why the readline has to be used at all... file.read() would do the job and no 'for a in lines' is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you have nothing returned. If your file looks like this:

```
BUILDING DATA:
N/A
```

I get using

```
import re
f = open('test.txt','r')
a = f.read(20)
re.search('BUILDING DATA:\nN/A', a, re.M)
```

an output. This is

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1004fc8b8>
```

If I test re.search with string, that is not in the file like in this code:

```
import re
f = open('test.txt','r')
a = f.read(20)
re.search('BUILDING BATA:\nN/A', a, re.M)
```

there is no output as expected.

EDIT:

As Saullo Castro pointed out, the problem is the line-by-line reading. Why not use something like this?

```
a = open('scan.txt','r').read()
if re.findall('BUILDING DATA:\nN/A', a, re.M):
     print('found!')
```

3rd try:

```
tmp = False
...
elif re.findall('BUILDING DATA:', a, re.M):
    tmp = True
elif tmp and re.findall('N/A', a, re.M):
    def_grid = ''
    print "Didn't find it"
    defense.append(def_grid)
    defense_count +=1
```

Comment: Yeah, you wrote, that in Notepad the text does not look as you have posted. Have you tried to search for 'BUILDING DATA:(LF)\nN/A'? It seems to me that there is some problem due to encoding.

Comment: +1 good point using `.read()`, but in the way the OP's algorithm is structured it may not work, but this is definitely a better approach than `''.join(lines)` after reading them...

Comment: Hmm.... I was reading the line because I need to pull parts of the line out and put them into a list and I need the location of the line. Also, i'm working around a situation where (sometimes its BUILDING DATA:\nN/A, and sometimes it includes the DEFENSE GRID) Inserting everything into a db for later use. Need to keep the keys consistant so I need to count the times its not there as well as when it is there.

Comment: Ah, sry, this I did not get. Ok...I think about something like 'elif re.search('BUILDING DATA:', a, re.M): if re.search('N/A', <next line>, re.M)'

Comment: @Xariec: This can surely be more elegant, but is my edit (3rd try) some kind of answer to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
re.findall('BUILDING DATA:\sN/A', a, re.M):
```

with

```
re.findall('BUILDING DATA:\nN/A', a, re.M):
```

or

```
re.search(r'BUILDING DATA:\nN/A', a, re.M):
```

and it should work.

(Notice that in your code there's `\s` instead of `\n`)

Comment: I like the shortcut `re.M`