# Python re.search is much slower than grep

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a python parser that loops through a large file line by line and looks for various strings and extracts strings/numbers using grouping. However, it takes a long time to do this as compared to just a grep/awk extraction combination

I tried ,

```
for line in fileA:
    line=line.strip()
    obj1Match=re.search("someString\s(.*?)\sOtherstring",line,re.I)
    if obj1Match:

        obj1Extract=obj1Match.group(1)

    missingEMatch=re.search("ERR(.*?)\sOtherString",line)
        if missingEMatch:
            if "missingErrors" in countDict:
                countDict["missingErrors"]+=1
            else:
                countDict["missingErrors"]=1
```

Above only has two examples, I have a long list of things to extract using capture groups and post process in various ways if it matches and python takes a long time surprisingly. On the other hand using grep/awk combination is blazing fast.

I'd like to know what exactly I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Well Python is _interpreted_ AFAIK, whereas `grep` or `awk` runs a few steps closer to the OS, directly on Linux.  I'm not surprised that a native function like `grep` would outperform Python.

Comment: As a side note, it is not `re.search()` the slowing bit, it is the `for` loop, have you tried it on the whole input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [re.search Multiple lines Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521319/re-search-multiple-lines-python)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by trying it on the whole input? I do a readLines() and read the entire file and then regex on the list?

Comment: I'm assuming that norok here was assuming that you were running [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html)s to compare the execution times between re.search and grep/awk, and that you may not have run re.search on the whole file contents (which grep/awk does) and only run it on one line of the file contents at a time. Essentially, it looks like you are not comparing similar situations. It would also help if you gave some actual numbers; like what is the size of the file, the number of lines, the time it takes for each to run (grep/awk vs re.search)

Answer (score 0):

While grep will run faster, you can make your current Python regex code faster by per-compiling your pattern.

Currently you are feeding in your regular expression to the engine for interpretation each time you call search. What you can do is compile your regex string into a regular expression pattern object and re-use it. This should give you significant performance gains.

```py
pattern = re.compile("someString\s(.*?)\sOtherstring", re.I)
missingpattern = re.compile("ERR(.*?)\sOtherString")

for line in fileA:
    line=line.strip()
    obj1Match=pattern.search(line)
    if obj1Match:
        obj1Extract=obj1Match.group(1)

    missingEMatch=missingpattern.search(line)
        if missingEMatch:
            if "missingErrors" in countDict:
                countDict["missingErrors"]+=1
            else:
                countDict["missingErrors"]=1
```

Comment: Helped by a couple of seconds but not drastically. I think the for loop is the issue here