# extracting word before character

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, positive-lookahead

I am trying to extract any word before `Y` which is boundary separated. As I am trying to consider each line as a separate record using `(?m)` flag and trying to capture `\w+` which is look ahead by `\s+Y` ,but I am only able to print 1st match, not the 2nd match(`IMP1`).

```
print(foo)
this is IMP Y text
and this is also IMP1 Y text
this is not so IMP2 N text
Y is not important
```

Current fruitless attempt:

```
>>> m = re.search('(?m).*?(\w+)(?=\s+Y)',foo)
>>> m.groups()
('IMP',)
>>>
>>> m = re.search('(?m)(?<=\s)(\w+)(?=\s+Y)',foo)
>>> m.groups()
('IMP',)
>>>
```

Expected result Is:

```
('IMP','IMP1')
```

Comment: [re.search Multiple lines Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521319/re-search-multiple-lines-python) can't be used to close this question as `re.M` is already used in the above code as an inline modifier `(?m)`. Just using `re.findall` won't help either, it will extract `text`, which is not expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\w+(?=[^\S\r\n]+Y\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bnsPaG/2). Details:

- `\w+` - one or more letters/digits/underscores
  -`(?=[^\S\r\n]+Y\b)` - immediately followed with one or more whitespaces other than CR and LF and then `Y` as a whole word (`\b` is a word boundary).

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/PrKtbA):

```
import re
foo = "this is IMP Y text\nand this is also IMP1 Y text\nthis is not so IMP2 N text\nY is not important"
print(re.findall(r'\w+(?=[^\S\r\n]+Y\b)', foo))
# => ['IMP', 'IMP1']
```

Comment: @monk `re.search` finds the first match only.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
(\w+)(?=.Y)
```

You can test [here](https://regex101.com/r/AXJGTf/1)

So, complete code would be:

```
import re

a="""this is IMP Y text
and this is also IMP1 Y text
this is not so IMP2 N text
Y is not important"""


print (re.findall(r"(\w+)(?=.Y)",a))
```

Output:

```
['IMP', 'IMP1']
```