# Search multi-line in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

On my project, i am looking for < td>F< /td> pattern in .txt file. Because I used html while converting files, patterns I didn't want appeared. For example, If there is  "< /tr>" after " < td>F< /td>" I don't write "F" my excel. I don't figure out how can i do it.

```
    <tr>
      <th>24</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>F</td>
    </tr>
```

```
re.compile(r'\\')
.
.
.
def findWordInText(name):
    a = name+".txt"
    count =0   
    with open(a,'r',encoding='utf-8',errors="ignore") as f:  
        line = f.read()
        i = 0        
        if("<td>F</td>")in line:
            search_txt = r"<td>F</td> \n        </tr>"
            if(search_txt)in line:
               print("F doesn't belong excel")
            else:
                txt="F"
                writeOnExcel(name,txt)
                count +=1
```

Comment: you mean multi-*line* right ?

Comment: It looks like your ".txt" file is really an html file - have you considered parsing the html using a library like `lxml` or just `html.parser`?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom yeah, sorry about that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [re.search Multiple lines Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521319/re-search-multiple-lines-python)

Comment: @Grismar my text so complex. Sometimes my word which i was looking for, embedded within text. On the other hand, I used camelot because I was trying to access the values in the tables inside the pdfs.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom I tried this but its not solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If its true structured html, beautifulsoup is the way to go in python.

If its just some text file, you can try

```
<td>F<\/td>(?!\s*<\/tr>)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/1F1a0Y/1